# C# adding dynamic variables in loop

Tags: c#, variables, dynamic

It's a pretty rookie question. 
Here is my code

```
double jury;
jury = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 0; i < jury ; i++)
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

How can I define the input inside the loop so I can use the input data from the additional inputs for math calculations.
It's a vote system and the first variable is the jury count - each jury member votes for a number 1-10. The idea is that the jury is dynamic from 1 to 100,000. Any ideas are welcome.

More: Here is the idea.

-> When you have for example 3 jury members

-> You input 3 on the first row

-> You get 3 new inputs where your jury vote for candidates ( numbers 1 to 10 )

-> In this case the votes are 1, 3, 3

The idea is to parse all this information and output the winner which in our case is "3".

Comment: You might want to go [google some examples of Console.ReadLine](http://www.dotnetperls.com/console-readline)

Comment: if you are using jury to store jury members count why it is double? can you have 3.5 juries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code prompts for a number of jurors and validates the input. Then, it prompts for each juror's vote, validating the vote input.

```
const int minimumVote = 1;
const int maximumVote = 10;
int jurorCount;

do
{
    Console.Write("Enter the number of jurors: ");
} while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out jurorCount) || jurorCount < 0);

var votes = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < jurorCount; i++)
{
    int vote;

    do
    {
        Console.Write("Enter juror #{0}'s vote ({1}-{2}): ", i + 1, minimumVote, maximumVote);
    } while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out vote) || vote < minimumVote || vote > maximumVote);

    votes.Add(vote);
}
```

Comment: I rewrote the code using a do/while instead of a while. That eliminated some extra lines. I also introduced two constants to keep from violating DRY.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `List<T>` to store votes; IMHO `int` looks better than `Double` in your task

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter number of jurors, please"); 

int jury;

if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out jury)) { 
  Console.WriteLine("Incorrect jury number format");

  return; // <- I'd exit on the first error occured; you may adopt different policy
}
else if ((jury < 1) || (jury > 100000)) {
  Console.WriteLine("Jury should be in range [1..100000]");

  return;
}

var List<int> = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < jury; ++i) {
  int vote;

  Console.WriteLine("Enter next vote, please"); 

  if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out vote)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect vote format");

    return;
  }
  else if ((vote < 1) || (vote > 10)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Each vote should be in range [1..10]");

    return;
  }

  votes.Add(vote);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a List or Array

```
var values = new List<double>();
for (int i = 0; i < jury; i++)
{
    double current;
    if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out current))
    {
       values.Add(current);
    }
    else
      i--;
}
```